# On the use of the expression $\text{marg}$ in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a problem with the use of the expression $\text{marg}$, so here there is an "example" (more than an example, this is an aid I would like to use to visualize what is going on).

The following is a table that describes the joint distribution of two discrete random variables.

[image]

Then we have the general formulae to get the marginal distributions for the two random variables:

$$g(x_1)= \sum_{x_2} p(x_1, x_2)$$

$$h(x_2)= \sum_{x_1} p(x_1, x_2)$$

which are - for example - the numbers on the right end of the table for the case $h(x_2)$.
(I guess this could seem quite unuseful, but I really need to actually visualize it in a concrete way)

Moving to an hypothetical continous case, we would have:

$$g(x_1)= \int_{X_2} p(x_1, x_2)d x_2$$

$$h(x_2)= \int_{X_1} p(x_1, x_2)d x_1$$

Now, here it comes my problem: how does the $\text{marg}$ notation comes into the picture? What should I think about when I find it?

What does exactly an expression like $\text{marg}_{X_1}$ mean?

Sorry for any mistake or sloppy statement, but all of this is really out of my knowledge.
Any help is more than welcome.

PS: I was not sure about the tag I had to use, because it is a rather general question.

Comment: If marginal is uncomfortable, one can leave the word out. The marginal distribution of $X_1$ is just the ordinary distribution of $X_1$.

Comment: The problem is not if it is uncomfortable or not. It is more that when I find that expression I don't know what to think about. Thus, this is an expression I cannot really avoid

Comment: For example, $\text{marg}_{X_1}$ should be something like "taking the marginal on $X_1$", right? But what does that mean exactly?

Comment: The point I was making is that the marginal distribution of $X_1$ is just the ordinary distribution of $X_1$. The word "marginal" arises because we are computing the distribution of $X_1$ from information about the joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: So, this means that when I see $\text{marg}_{X_1}$ I have to focus on $X_1$, out of the original joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$?

Comment: Yes, that's all. The word marginal comes from the fact that in the discrete case it is given by the sums on the left and bottom margins, as in old-syle accounting.

Comment: I can hardly explain you how much you helped me.

Comment: That's what MSE is about.